# Amazon AWS EC2 React App gets blocked (Content Security Policy)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

So I did the deployment exactly like here: https://medium.com/@rksmith369/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-nginx-the-right-way-e76c1a8cd6c6

But my React App wont load, instead it gets blocked(Content Security Policy).

Maybe something with nginx? Or is my React app broken? I was searching the whole day so I thought I give it a try and ask for help.

**Edit:
New Problem my homepage gets loaded, but on all of the other sites I get a 404 if I reload...**

**New Server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const http = require('http')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

// Body Parser Middleware:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connected'))
  .catch(() => console.log('DB Connection Error:', err))

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
})

// Assign socket object to every request
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.io = io
  next()
})

// Routes
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/order')

// Middleware
app.use('/api', orderRoutes)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

server.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server läuft auf Port: ${PORT}`))
```

**React App package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "antd": "^4.15.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not with your React App or the your server, but its with your helmet configuration.
Update your CORS configuration to provide a valid content security policy. For example

```
app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
            'script-src': ["'self'", 'https://apis.google.com'],
            'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https://fonts.googleapis.com'],
            'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https://accounts.google.com' ],
            'img-src': ['https:', 'data:'],
        },
    },
}));
```

To read more about CSP checkout this

1. [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)
2. [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet)

Comment: So I managed to get it atleast loading the homepage. If I click on different sites they get loaded until i reload them. After I reload I get a 404 not found and Content Security Policy Error. Probably a nginx problem?? Hopefully someone can help...

Comment: React apps are SPA, the files built after compiling are not the same as your route names. So when you search for try to refresh order page node js is unable to find a file names order.html in your frontend, neither do you have a route named /order. so it returns 404. Add this "app.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/index.html'));" at the end of your server.js to solve this issue.

Comment: Also if my answer helped you solve the issue, please up vote so others can also get benefited thanks !

Comment: Solved my Issue. Thank you!